# How to prevent route change based on async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, async-await, next.js

In my Next.js app, I'm calling an upload function which contains the `then` and `catch` functions.

```js
export const uploadDocument = async (url: UploadURLs, file: File) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", file);
  await fetch(`${someEndpoint}`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
  })
    .then(() => notify(`Awesome, it worked.`, "success"))
    .catch(() => notify("An error occurred.", "error"));
};
```

> Note: The `notify` function is a wrapper function firing a toast notification, and isn't really important to my question.

From my component, I'm calling the `uploadDocument` function. Everything is working, but **I can't stop `router.push(nextPage)` from firing (shown below), regardless of whether the `uploadDocument` function succeeds or not.**

**I want to keep the `then` and `catch` logic inside the `uploadDocument` function, but also would like to have the calling component know whether or not the upload succeeded, so I could prevent the page change.**

```js
const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    await uploadDocument(
      "certificate",
      file
    )
    router.push(nextPage); // This always fires, but should be conditional
  };
```

I tried to capture the result of the function call, but get `undefined` regardless of upload success/failure:

```
const result = await uploadDocument("certificate", file);
if (result.success) router.push(nextPage);
```

Comment: Remove the `.then` and the `.catch` and wrap your `await fetch...` around a try/catch block and then you can simply return "true" or "false" to indicate whether the process was successful or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the advice of @kemicofa-ghost, as they pointed out in the comments, and arrived at a working solution.

```js
export const uploadDocument = async (url: UploadURLs, file: File) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", file);

  try {
    await fetch(`${someEndpoint}`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    });
    notify(`Your file ${file.name} was uploaded successfully`, "success");
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    notify(
      "An error occurred while uploading the file. Please try again.",
      "error"
    );
    return false;
  }
};
```

And then:

```js
const result = await uploadDocument(
  "certificate",
  companyInfo2.incorporationCertificate
);

if (result) router.push(nextPage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
export const uploadDocument = (url: UploadURLs, file: File) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", file);
  return fetch(`${someEndpoint}`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
  })
};
```

Then you can catch the error with an `try /catch`

```
const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
    
       await uploadDocument(
         "certificate",
         file
       )
       notify(`Awesome, it worked.`, "success")
       router.push(nextPage);
 
    } catch(err) {
       notify("An error occurred.", "error")
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get things working this way, too, but didn't want to expose the `notify` logic outside of the `uploadDocument` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your logic in your function:

```
type UploadResponse = {
  error: boolean;
  message: string;
}
export const uploadDocument = async (url: UploadURLs, file: File): Promise<UploadResponse> => {
  try {

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", file);
  await fetch(`${someEndpoint}`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
  })
  
    return {error: false, message: "Awesome, it worked"}
  } catch(e) {
    return {error: true, message: "An error occurred"}
  }
};

const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const result = await uploadDocument(
      "certificate",
      file
    )

    notify(result.message);
    if (!result.error) {
      router.push(nextPage);
    }
  };
```